# Using the Metropolitan Museum API tags parameter

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I have no problem using the Metropolitan Museum of Art API, except for the "tags" parameter.

Here is their description of the tags format.

| Parameter | Format | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tags | Boolean, true or false. Case sensitive. | Returns objects that match the query, specifically searching against the subject keyword tags field for objects. |

Here is what is returned when I console log the tag *response* of an object.

```
[
    {
        "term": "Lions",
        "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300310388",
        "Wikidata_URL": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q140"
    },
    {
        "term": "Men",
        "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025928",
        "Wikidata_URL": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q8441"
    },
    {
        "term": "Hunting",
        "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300239666",
        "Wikidata_URL": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q36963"
    },
    {
        "term": "Dogs",
        "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300265714",
        "Wikidata_URL": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q144"
    }
]
```

The Met website seems to suggest that you can search objects by tags but I can't find a way to do this within the format. `tag=Lions` for example returns mostly works with the "Lions" tag, but also a work with only the tags "Ships" and "Calligraphy". So it seems to be a boolean checking whether or not there are tags. I would want it to return ONLY "Lions". I'm honestly baffled by this behavior.

Comment: What end point are you using?

Comment: @KevinZ I forgot to include this important information. In the example, I am using `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/search?isHighlight=true&q=dogs&tags=Lions`. Another thing about the tags parameter is that it seems to require a search query as well (in this case dogs).

Answer (score 0):

As you cite, the [MET API manual](https://metmuseum.github.io/) is quite clear: format for the parameter `tags` is:     "Boolean, true or false. Case sensitive.". This means that it can be `tags=true`or `tags=false`. In your case instead of

https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/search?isHighlight=true&q=dogs&tags=Lions

you want (for searching "Lions" in the tags)

https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/search?isHighlight=true&tags=true&q=Lions